# Is there a way to make a JQuery post array be dynamic?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to make `var changes` be a variable that you can put into this array below?

```
    $(".SUBMIT").on("click", function(){
        var name = $("#idvalue").val();
        var changes = "thischanges"; // this variable changes the key 
        $.post("ajax_process.php",{ changes: name}, function(data){
            alert(data);
        });
    });// END submit

$_POST['changes']; // will be what sends through, is there a way to make it the variable every time?
```

This would be similar to  `key, value` but making a key that changes with your variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to construct object in two steps and use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) for variable property name:

```
$(".SUBMIT").on("click", function(){
    var name = $("#idvalue").val();
    var changes = "thischanges";

    var data = {}
    data[changes] = name; // set dynamic property name

    $.post("ajax_process.php", data, function(data){
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

With ES2015 standard, you can use [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names):

```
$(".SUBMIT").on("click", function(){
    var name = $("#idvalue").val();
    var changes = "thischanges";

    $.post("ajax_process.php",{[changes]: name}, function(data){
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: That absolutely worked great! :)